# spring oauth2 resource server custom logic to validate token and set authentication object

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

My requirement is that i want to create my resource server whose resources would be secured via an **external authorization server**.

**The external authorization server has below properties.**

> 1. It provides its own sign-in sign-up pages.
> 2. It redirects to my resource server URL via a returnURL(resource server url) specified when requesting sign-in.
> 3. it sends the access token , user GUID (uniqueId) as parameters when redirecting to returnURL ( resource server url ).
> 4. It provides api to check the token validity.
> 5. It provides api to get the User info via access token.

I am now able to secure and access my resource server resources with the use of **Interceptors**.  The interceptor comes into action whenever a resource is accessed. **it takes below actions.**

> 1. If access token is not present in the cookie, then it redirects to auth server sign-in page with details ( clientId, returnURL etc)
> 2. if access token is present in cookie then it calls the auth server api to validate. ( if GUID of the validated token is not same as
>      session GUID ) then redirect to signin page.
> 3. If GUID is same then check cache for the user details. if details is not present then request User info from auth server api via access
>      token.
> 4. Finally create a user principal and save in session.

*But I want to use spring security oauth2 resource server configurations.*

***How can i override implementation of spring security oauth2 resource server configuration to implement above logic ?***

Comment: anyone who can help ??